angular project first time load is very slow because of vendor.js is 3 MB
I am using angular 8. My vendor.js file is very big.
Please tell me how do I reduce it.
i tried 1. buillding with production configuration 2. aot = true 3, vendorchunk =true 4. namedchunk= true 5. lazy loading 6. ivy compiler but still the vendor.js file is 3 mb
my production configuration-

              "optimization": true
              "outputHashing": "all"
              "sourceMap": false
              "extractCss": true
              "namedChunks": true
              "aot": true
              "extractLicenses": true
              "vendorChunk": true
              "buildOptimizer": true


try using webpack-bundle-analyzer to see which vendor does this, maybe you"re importing a big lib that can't tree shake
